# How do I get the name of the partial loaded by handlebars.js ( client or server side node/express )?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
{{>partialname}}
```

How do I get "partialname" above to reflect when loading the partial?

i.e

```
partialname.handlebars
```

I can get the layout file name and the root template name, but this method which uses exposed variables by the register helpers does not give you the partial name.

I am using express and Handlebars.js

The best-case scenario would be for the rendered partial above to have its name render on the client browser with a full path , but at this point, just the name would be good enough, it could be client-side or server-side.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you want to render a partial or just the name (or file path) of a partial.

Comment: just the name (or file path) of a partial, the purpose is better explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364641/i-would-like-to-be-able-to-load-edit-handlebars-js-templates-express-server/68503589#68503589

Comment: I still don't understand. The way you are using `partialname` in your example suggests you have a partial registered with the name "partialname" - however, I don't think that is your intention. I think you need to provide some clarity around what "partialname" is supposed to be. For example, is it a variable?

Comment: No it should not be a variable, it would be any old partial name i.e {{>navigation}} or {{>button}}. What I cannot get is to have "navigation" reflect on the loaded partial, or similarly "button". Basically, I am trying to get the file name of the partial "navigation.handlebars" or similarly "button.handlebars". It seems really easy , but I am concerned that I need to start messing with the handlebars back end to get this.

Comment: I would just pass a hardcoded value as an additional parameter in my partial call. For example, `{{>button partialname="button.handlebars"}}`. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/oed8vr9u/

Comment: Thanks, I am currently doing this, it does works, but not a lot of  "finesse".